# Python.exe hangs in Miniconda2 on Windows using Cygwin

Tags: python, windows, failed-installation, miniconda

I installed Miniconda2 on Windows and am using Cygwin. I found the `Miniconda2/Scripts` folder that has the `conda.exe` and have been able to successfully `conda install` packages.

However, after following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814361/miniconda-installs-numpy-but-python-cant-import-it) and using `export` to redirect my Path to the `Python.exe` (`which python` does give me the correct Python.exe), I cannot even run Python anymore. It just hangs.

However, if I locate the file using Windows File Explorer and just double click the Python.exe file, it does run Python and successfully finds the imported packages. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Can you run the interactive REPL? If not, does running `python -i` make it work? Can you run a script that prints to stdout, e.g. `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`?

Comment: Ahh yes I had completely forgotten about the `-i` flag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Miniconda2 working in Windows, I added the following to my `.profile`

```
export PATH="~/Miniconda2/Scripts:$PATH"
export PATH="~/Miniconda2/:$PATH"
```

Finally, I added the following alias in my `.bashrc`

```
alias python="python -i"
```