# Have I appended the right filepath to sys.path for Conda to notice it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conda, miniconda

I'm a mathematician who's self-teaching data science, so forgive me if this is a noob question.
I'm running miniconda on Windows and ran into what seems to be a path problem; miniconda contains numpy and pandas but Python can't find it. [Miniconda "installs" numpy but Python can't import it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814361/miniconda-installs-numpy-but-python-cant-import-it#comment53465244_32814361) said it was likely a path error; https://stackoverflow.com/a/36354847/4540218 recommended I append the file path to sys.path; [Where does Anaconda Python install on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117571/where-does-anaconda-python-install-on-windows) says that path can be found before the angle bracket in the Conda command line.

But neither `C:\\Users\\myName\\.conda`, which is the actual address, or `C:\\Users\\myName\\miniconda3`, which is what it said in the environments.txt file I found there, seem to work. Moreover, the environments.txt file appears to be the ONLY thing in that folder. I would have expected a Python install.
Even weirder:

```
(base) C:\Users\benja>where anaconda
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Is what I get when I try to use the Windows command where to find it, as another commenter recommended.
Have I misunderstood something about all this?

Comment: Have you tried a clean install? If conda is installed correctly, then you do not to manually adjust the `sys.path`.  `C:\\Users\\myName\\miniconda3`or `C:\\Users\\myName\\Anaconda3` is the correct folder. Your installation just seems to be broken. Try to reinstall.

Comment: Can you run `echo %CONDA_PREFIX%` and `where python` in the miniconda command prompt and report the result?

Comment: So... I guess that means reinstall. Sigh. Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid when I uninstalled I lost the exact text of the results, but %CONDA_PREFIX% was miniconda3 and where python returned two different results, one of which was in miniconda3. So I concluded the path was right and my install was just broken.

Comment: Uninstalled. Reinstalled. Reinstalled Numpy. Something interesting has happened: (DS101) C:\Users\myName\Documents\Udacity_DS101>echo %CONDA_PREFIX%
C:\Users\myName\miniconda3\envs\DS101

(DS101) C:\Users\myName\Documents\Udacity_DS101>where python
C:\Users\myName\miniconda3\envs\DS101\python.exe
C:\Users\myName\miniconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe In other words, there is now another python install inside the environment. That wasn't there before. Still can't find Numpy.